# Angular injector not passing deps

Tags: angular

I have problem with `injector`.

I build an abstract class that is base for custom components. That's why for constructor I use `Injector` - for simplyfiy child classes.

```
export abstract class SchematerLayout implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @Input() public form: FormGroup;
    @Input() public field: IFieldConfig;
    @ViewChild('fieldComponent', {read: ViewContainerRef}) fieldComponent: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(protected injector: Injector) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const componentResolver = this.injector.get(SchematerComponentResolverService);
        const validationMessagesService = this.injector.get(SchematerValidationMessagesService);
    }
}
```

Problem is that `SchematerValidationMessagesService` gets always error `Can't resolve all parameters for SchematerValidationMessagesService: (?).`
And `SchematerComponentResolverService` depends on the same service.

Here is my `SchematerValidationMessagesService` class:

```
@Injectable()
export class SchematerValidationMessagesService {
    constructor(
        protected configService: SchematerConfigService
    ) {
    }

    getErrorMessage(fieldControl: AbstractControl, fieldConfig: IFieldConfig) {
        //...
    }
}
```

And `SchematerComponentResolverService` class:

```
@Injectable()
export class SchematerComponentResolverService {
    constructor(protected componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                protected configService: SchematerConfigService
    ) {
    }

    createLayoutComponent(type: string) {
        // console.log(type);
    }
}
```

I'm getting providers with `forRoot` strategy:

```
static forRoot(config: SchematerConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: SchematerInputModule,
        providers: [
            {
                provide: SchematerConfig,
                useValue: config,
            },
            {
                provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
                useValue: config,
                multi: true
            },
            SchematerConfigService,
            SchematerValidationMessagesService,
            SchematerComponentResolverService,

        ]
    };
}
```

Can anyone give my a clue why `SchematerConfigService` is available for first service and not for second?

Comment: It means that `SchematerConfigService` is undefined during execution `SchematerValidationMessagesService` class. Most likely you have circular dependency

Comment: But why it is available earlier? I paseted complete `SchematerValidationMessagesService ` class - no other depencies

Comment: Create reproduction in minimal example on github. Users often find coding problems themselves while preparing a minimal reproduction.

Comment: Problem are my entryComponents that has depencies. I have to make some changes - thank You